# After dynamical adding options to select box, trigger doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select box with with id `test`. I have trigger on it like:

```
$("#test").on('change', function() { alert('test'); })
```

And that works for the first time, but after I add some options to select box dynamically like:

```
var option = $("<option>")
          .attr('value', this.value)
          .attr('class', this.class)
          .html(this.text);

        // if id corresponds to selected id then select it
        if (parseInt(this.value) == selected_id) {
          option.attr('selected', 'selected');
        }

        // append to select
        $("#test").append(option);
```

trigger doesn't work. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$(document).on('change', '#test', function() { alert('test'); });
```

With the following:

```
    var trigger = false;
    if (parseInt(this.value) == selected_id) {
      option.attr('selected', 'selected');
      trigger = true;
    }

    // append to select
    $("#test").append(option);
    !trigger || $('#test').change();
```

**NOTE:** By just adding a `selected` attribute to a new option, the `select` element won't trigger. You have to explicitly trigger it using `.change()` or `.trigger('change')` when applicable. When a user manually selects a value, both the `value` is set and the `change` event is triggered at the same time (if the new value is not equal to the previous value).

Comment: @harisb2012 I just made an update that might be helpful, if you're looking for the select to trigger programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

var option = "`<option value='"+this.value+"' class='"+this.class+"'>"+this.text+"</option>`";
`$("#test").append(option)`;

Instead of doing:

```
var option = $("<option>")
          .attr('value', this.value)
          .attr('class', this.class)
          .html(this.text);
```

And then appending it.

Could you post the entire script? Or at least a more complete example?